# django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: django

When I add in the configuration of logging I get this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 176, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/functools.py", line 448, in wrapper
    result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 71, in get_commands
    for app_config in reversed(list(apps.get_app_configs())):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 137, in get_app_configs
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

If I do not specify any logging settings, runserver runs fine.
Logging settings:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'special': {
            '()': 'project.logging.SpecialFilter',
            'foo': 'bar',
        },
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'filters': ['special']
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'myproject.custom': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filters': ['special']
        }
    }
}
```

Tried other logging settings as well, but still the same error

Comment: so when you remove the whole `LOGGING` variable, it works?

Answer (score 1):

made a mistake in determining the filter) That solved the problem